# Two eclipse installations with completely separate development environments

Tags: eclipse, pydev, gnu

I am an Eclipse newbie (on Windows 7).  Is it possible to have two Eclipse installations at the same time where one is customized for Python development (via PyDev), and the other for embedded C development (through GNU toolchains)?  If so, how would one go about doing this?  If one of the Eclipse environments is already installed, what should I pay attention to when installing the second environment?  (Or is there another, completely different approach that only uses one copy of Eclipse, but multiple plug-ins? Just thinking out loud here.)

I am apprehensive of things (plugins, workspaces, environment variables, etc.) getting mixed up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just install the second Eclipse in a separate directory and use separate workspaces and there should not be any problem. Eclipse keeps all the configuration information about the installation in its install directory. All information about a workspace is kept in the workspace.

Answer (score 1):

Get the zip-version of eclipse, unzip it into two different folders, and create a separate workspace for each of them. Then install plug ins etc.. This works on Linux;  I don't see why it shouldn't work on Windows.